# AddressBook Swift: Cannot invoke 'searchElementForProperty' with an argument list

Tags: macos, swift, addressbook

While working with `AddressBook`, with the code below:

```
var find:ABSearchElement  = ABPerson.searchElementForProperty(kABLastNameProperty, label: nil, key: nil, value: "LastName", comparison: kABEqual)
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot invoke 'searchElementForProperty' with an argument list of type '(String, label: nil, key: nil, value: String, comparison: _ABSearchComparison)'
```

I also tried putting empty strings instead of `nil`s, but no success.
Any ideas?